# A genre about hidden/secret history of the world

Tags: books, history-of, science-fiction-genre, h-p-lovecraft

I am looking for a genre that I cannot really find to have a common name, but what can be described as a secret or hidden history of the world.

Much like Lovecraft where his heroes were studying ancient manuscripts to uncover the ancient and forgotten knowledge. Where the ancient people knew things that were discovered long after that can only be explained by some facts unknown to modern science.

I tried to google, but could not find anything interesting. Since it's not really allowed to ask about the authors themselves I would appreciate any hints that can help me google this. A common name for the genre, or some other least common denominator that I can use to search e.g.

P.S. Not looking for "documentary" conspiracy theories, but pure fiction.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Requests for lists of works or recommendations are off-topic as they do not fit our questions and answers format. Feel free to ask about people's favorites in chat.

Comment: Thanks :) I see, that's a pity. It's not like I am looking for a recommendation, but just a some authors who work in this genre. Do you know if any other stack exchange site is suited for this? I am also not sure which chart you are talking about?

Comment: Not chart...chat. And , as I said, *Requests for lists of works (and in this case authors) are off-topic*

Comment: Sorry, mistype :) Thanks for help anyway, it's a pity these questions are off topic

Comment: Michael Chabon, Alan Moore's League of Extraordinary Gentlemen comic books, and Warren Ellis' Planetary comic books.

Comment: Sometimes people have good questions that they word poorly because they asked it too early, or simply that they can't find the right terms to ask it with. These do not make bad questions, and nuking the questions because you're not smart enough to see that doesn't make for a very welcoming environment, or a very good questions/answers site. Those he is nominally asking for a "list", the real question is "how do I define this unlabeled genre well enough to search for it". That's a good question. Edit it into that good question.

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik Here's a [link](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley) to the main Sci-fi & Fantasy chat room. Do come and join in :-) Pretty much anything is 'on-topic' in chat, so questions like yours would be more than welcome there.

Comment: I have now edited the question to not violate the rules, since it's not requesting for a list, but just the genre as @JohnO has suggested

Comment: Check out Tim Powers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two such genres, really. The first is well-known, that would be the "spy thriller", sometimes put down as "espionage". Not all spy thrillers contain "secret histories", only a (not small) subset do. Everything's classified, only a few people ever really know the truth of what happened.

The other genre I do not know a good label for, but it tends to not involve spies or intelligence agencies. Private individuals are the main protagonists and antagonists. If government agencies are involved, it's only temporarily or tangentially so (television: Supernatural, The Librarians). The secrets are often of a supernatural/fantasy/science fiction nature.

Sometimes both are combined (Hellboy movies, Charles Stross's stuff).

I propose that the latter genre/category be called "covert fantasy". We could tag it as such, and without even checking I know that there will be several other questions that would use it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I'll try to check, though "covert fantasy" won't yield any good results in google as of now :) I am mostly interested in the sub-genre of the "covert fantasy" where the ancient secrets are uncovered that shed the light on some pre-historic puzzles involving some forgotten advanced civilizations/ aliens/ other worlds, etc. Like Lovecraft, but not necessarily horror :) It's a pity it's nearly impossible to find something like that in Google.